# Check words down a column with another sheet containing valid values and backfilling it

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Example]

I have a list of valid values for each column in Style 1, 2 3 4 in another sheet of the same excel file. 
For example

- Style 1: Red Green Yellow
- Style 2: High Low Up Down
- Style 3: Dog Mouse

I have a few columns: `Description`, `Description_2` and so on,  that contains many words. What I would like to do is to check every word in these Description and then compare with all of the valid values in the Styles.

If the word matches any of the valid value, then it will put the value in the row.

**Example**: Checking `Description`, it realizes that `Dog` is a valid value in `Style 3`. So cell E2 will have `Dog` inside. 
`Green, yellow` is valid value in `Style 1`. Cell B2 will have `Yellow, Green`.
Then it checks `Description_2` and so on.

So it should compare all of the `Description`, `Description_2` and so on, and put in the appropriate words in the style columns if it matches the valid values.

I have many thousand rows of data, and it should put all the words accordingly in each row and column.

I am not very sure of the approach in VBA as I am very new to VBA.

Comment: You need a couple of splits, a few loops and possibly a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim stylesRng As Range, cell As Range, f As Range
    Dim word As Variant

    With Worksheets("Styles") ' change "Styles" to your actual sheet name with "styles" columns
        Set stylesRng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:A", "C:C").Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' change "A:A", "C:C" to your actual "Styles" sheet columns with styles indexes
    End With

    With Worksheets("Descriptions") ' change "Descriptions" to your actual sheet name with "Descriptions" columns
        For Each cell In Intersect(.Range("H:H, J:J, L:L"), .Rows("2:" & .Rows.Count)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' change "H:H, J:J, L:L" to your actual "Descriptions" sheet columns with Descriptions indexes
            For Each word In Split(cell, " ")
                Set f = stylesRng.Find(what:=word, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    With .Rows(1).Find(what:=f.Parent.Cells(1, f.Column), lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(cell.Row - 1)
                        .Value = .Value & word & " "
                    End With
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do I get Runtime Error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment at the  8th line Set stylesRng=Intersect...? How does this code know which column style to assign, is it due to the first index row?

Comment: ^ that happens when you write code for the OP who tried nothing at all yet and then even don't explain your code (what you did and why that way). Code only answers are a bad practice, because neither the OP nor further readers can learn from it :(

Comment: @VictorToh, as you can read in comments, "styles" columns are to be listed in `.Range("A:A", "C:C")` portion of that code line: as it is it assumes that "styles" columns are columns A, B and C

Comment: @Peh, I put comments, which I think are all is needed by now since OP's didn't give any code and hence I can't know how far is he. By reading his subsequent comments we can go further

Comment: Alright I have analyzed the code and understand better. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome. did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it out with a few rows but my file has upwards of 100000 rows and more than 50 style columns so it will take time

Comment: @Peh, _"I have analyzed the code and understand better"_: I do think that this is the best attitude and way to learn

Comment: @DisplayName Well, I might have a different opinion on that (to cite the help center: *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*). If people have no explanations they "analyze" code "think" they understood, but without explanation they might understand it wrong, as we often see how eg. `On Error Resume Next` is used wrong (where people "think" they know how it works). Just saying: Better write full explanations especially when the answer is not a trivial change of an OPs code. Just good to see if you understand the code the right way.